# Toggle the visibility using Ajax and radio buttons

Tags: php, ajax

On my **page1.php** I want to toggle the visibility of the **page2.php**.

I am using the following code:

```
<input type="radio" name="city" value="Barcelona" onclick="getPage2(this.value);"> Barcelona
<input type="radio" name="city" value="Manchester"> Manchester
```

I call the **page2.php** using this code:

```
function getPage2()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "page2.php",
        success: function(result){
            $("#show_results").html(result);
        }
    });
};
```

I want to show the page2.php only if the radio button is selected and show nothing (Hide it) if none of the radio buttons, or the 'Machester' radio button is selected.

---

**UPDATE**

I solved it. It was actually very easy.

```
<input type="radio" name="city" value="Barcelona" onclick="getPage2(this.value);"> Barcelona
<input type="radio" name="city" value="Manchester" onclick="getPage2(this.value);"> Manchester
```

I show and I hide the **page2.php** using this code:

```
function getPage2()
        {

    var var_name = $("input[name='city']:checked").val();

     $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "page2.php",
                success: function(result){


     if(var_name == "Barcelona")
               $("#show_results").html(result).show();
              else
                $("#show_results").html(result).hide();
                }
            });
        };
```

Thank guys anyway.

Comment: Hi Max, I don't want to hide the clicked input. I want to hide the page3.php which I am calling when I click on radio button Barcelona

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JQuery selector for that :

```
$('input').click(function(){
    $('input').show(); // Show all inputs
    $(this).hide(); // Hide the clicked input

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "page2.php",
        success: function(result){
            $("#show_results").html(result);
        }
    });
})
```

Of course, this works only for a page with those inputs only.

You should have classes or IDs to your radios to target them directly with the selector.

You will have something like this :

`$('.radio-page').click(function(){ // ...`

Answer (score 0):

You could just load the hide-able content WITH the original page. That way you can avoid the ajax call.

```
<input class="radios" type="radio" name="city" value="Barcelona"> Barcelona
<input class="radios" type="radio" name="city" value="Manchester"> Manchester
<div id="content" style="display:none">Hide-able content</div>
```

And then just have the script make it appear when Barcelona is selected.

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function()
{
    if($(this).val() == "Barcelona") $("#content").show();
    else $("#content").hide();

});
```

Comment: Hi Sanckke, I want to hide the page2.php not a div.

Comment: @SunZ Can you not put the contents of page2.php inside of a div?

Comment: Yes I can. But I want to learn how to hide the content of another page. It will help me a lot on my project.

Comment: I tested your example, but didn't work. Can you check please?

Comment: @SunZ I'm sorry I did have an error, I updated the code.